# ipad img scaling css error

Tags: html, css, ipad

Right now I'm working on a one pager web site. The site seems ok although we still have things to do. But my main problem is with scaling on ipad. If you try to open site on ipad http://www.4-sport.co/sis you will notice that the background img is scaled wrong. It gets small and positioned on top-left corner. What should I do to correct it?

Thank you

```
/* ==========================================================================
   Header Styles
   ========================================================================== */
/* iphone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
   img { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
   img { max-width: 100%; }
}

#header{overflow:hidden;height:auto;background: url('../img/bg.png') fixed no-repeat; height:100%;}
.no-touch #header{-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;}

#logo{display:none;}
#logo img{width:100px;}

/* Intro Styles */

#intro{text-align: center;}  
#intro h1{margin-top: 0.5em;margin-bottom: 0;color: white;font-size: 1.875em;opacity:0;padding-top: 2em;}
#intro h2{margin-bottom: 0;font-size: 1.5em;opacity:0;padding-top: 2em;}
#intro p{color:white;}

#explore {opacity:0;margin-top: 0em;}
#explore a {text-decoration: none;}
#explore a i{font-size:6em;margin:0 auto; color:white; cursor:pointer; color:white;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}
.touch #explore a i:hover,.no-touch #explore a i:hover{color:#f4594e;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For no-touch devices you have the CSS:

```
.no-touch #header {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This is responsible for the *correct* scaling of the image. You need this for touch devices (iPad, etc.) as well. So just set the CSS properties to `#header` and delete `.no-touch #header { ... }`

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Now it's working but the problem is the pic seems terrible and too big. How can I make it fit the screen and seem better?

Comment: I guess the image is to small. The iPad 3 for instance has a display resolution of 1536px by 2048px.